# Get Cookie from within ActionFilterAttribute context

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cookies

How to get cookie value from within ActionFilterAttribute context?

there is no Cookies under actionContext.Request.Cookies.
and can't find the cookies anywhere under Request object.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace MapManager.Helpers
{
    public class CheckCsrfHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.Method == System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post 
                || actionContext.Request.Method == System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Put 
                || actionContext.Request.Method == System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Delete)
            {
               //GetCookies does not exist
               var cookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("XSRF-TOKEN").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var accessToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("access_token");
```

`HttpRequestHeadersExtensions.GetCookies` is in `System.Net.Http`,
so have to include `System.Net.Http`